# DataLakeServiceClient throws authentication error using TokenCredentials

Tags: azure, token, azure-data-lake

Reading from DataLakeServiceClient is resulting in:

*Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature*

This happens when I use the TokenCredentials which I create using the token I get from AAD for the current user.

**Note:** If I use StorageSharedKeyCredential and specify the account key everything works fine and I can read the data.

How do I get it to work with TokenCredentials? I want to authenticate that the user has permissions to read the direct file and not circumvent this security check using the account key.

```
public DataLakeServiceClient GetDataLakeServiceClient(string token)
{
    string accountName = "***";
    AzureTokenCrential azureTokenCredential = new AzureTokenCrential(token);
    string dfsUri = "***";
    DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), azureTokenCredential);

    return dataLakeServiceClient;
}

DataLakeServiceClient client = this.GetDataLakeServiceClient(token);
DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = client.GetFileSystemClient("");
DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("TestBlobContainer");
DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.GetFileClient("TestFile.txt");
Response<FileDownloadInfo> downloadResponse = await fileClient.ReadAsync();
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(downloadResponse.Value.Content);
string text = textReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Thanks!

--Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure identity client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity) to authenticate your application with Azure AD.

This example creates a `DataLakeServiceClient` instance by using a client ID, a client secret, and a tenant ID. To get these values, see Acquire a token from [Azure AD for authorizing requests from a client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app).

```
public void GetDataLakeServiceClient(ref DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient, 
    String accountName, String clientID, string clientSecret, string tenantID)
{

    TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantID, clientID, clientSecret, new TokenCredentialOptions());

    string dfsUri = "https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";

    dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), credential);
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this article about [connecting by using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet#connect-by-using-azure-active-directory-ad).

Comment: I don't want to authenticate the application, but rather the user using the application.

Comment: How do you generate your token?

Comment: I tried these using DefaultAzureCredential():

1.  DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), new DefaultAzureCredential(true)) ;

2. Also tried passing TokenCredential() with a wrapper class that sets Token to the string received from essentially LoginSilentAsync()